# IDE para python 3.8.1 de bajos recursos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola estoy buscando una ide de python para mi laptop

requisitos de mi pc:
AMD V160 2.4 ghz
2gb ram

he probado ERIC(eric era poco practico) y Ninja ide(no me funcionaba) y no me han gustado.

ahora mismo uso GEANY pero me gustaria probar otros

(no recomienden Pycharm lo he utilizado y gasta mas recursos que 20 pestañas de google abiertas mas o menos!)

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Hola ticua, tal como comenta Aprendiz, tu pregunta se basa en gran parte en opiniones personales y recomendaciones (aunque podamos medir el consumo de memoria o uso de cpu). Puedes probar [Thony](https://thonny.org/) (básico pero consume poco, viene preinstalado con Raspbian por ejemplo). Otra opción es [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) bastante más completo y algo más pesado (mucho menos que Eric o PyCharm), enfocado especialmente al ámbito científico.  Un saludo.